# Проверка верстки масштабированием

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Относительно часто заказчики пишут, что та или иная кнопочка съезжает при масштабировании сайта. Действительно ли это нужно учитывать или это небольшая путаница между проверкой на других разрешениях экрана?

Comment: Тут уже надо ругать обозреватель, а не верстальщика, ибо у каждого обозревателя своё мнение по поводу масштабирования.

Comment: Сам хотел задать этот вопрос, потому что как раз на днях были разговоры с заказчиком, где он жаловался на те или иные дефекты при 90% zoom'e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Масштабирование в браузере сделали для того, чтобы можно было лучше рассмотреть текст или картинку. Если не предполагается, что пользователь будет масштабировать страницу, то верстку так проверять нельзя. Для разных разрешений верстку можно проверить через консоль хрома например, активировав соответствующий пункт. Конкретно пункт называется device metrics.